# Kernel deprecation warning with fnpct

Tags: latex-base, fnpct

I recently upgraded to TeXLive 2018 (and pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)) and now I notice that package *fnpct* generates the following warnings:

```
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "kernel/deprecated-variant"
* 
* Variant form 'V' deprecated for base form '\peek_meaning_remove:NTF'. One
* should not change an argument from type 'N' to type 'V': base form only
* accepts a single token argument.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "kernel/deprecated-variant"
* 
* Variant form 'V' deprecated for base form '\token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF'. One
* should not change an argument from type 'N' to type 'V': base form only
* accepts a single token argument.
*************************************************
```

Are they harmless? Should I report this to the author of fnpct?

### Minor update

As of a recent (2018-12-10) update to TeXLive 2018 these warnings have changed to the following:

```
LaTeX3 Warning: Variant form 'V' deprecated for base form
(LaTeX3)        '\peek_meaning_remove:NTF'. One should not change an argument
(LaTeX3)        from type 'N' to type 'V': base form only accepts a single
(LaTeX3)        token argument.


LaTeX3 Warning: Variant form 'V' deprecated for base form
(LaTeX3)        '\token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF'. One should not change an argument
(LaTeX3)        from type 'N' to type 'V': base form only accepts a single
(LaTeX3)        token argument.
```

I suspect it does not change the accepted answer, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are 'code level' warnings, so as a user you should not need to worry. However, just in case the package maintainer misses them, you may wish to report them.

Comment: Done: see [report on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/fnpct/issues/13/kernel-warnings-with-recent-version-of).

Comment: I guess that `\peek_meaning_remove:VTF` should be `\exp_last_unbraced:NV \peek_meaning_remove:NTF` and similarly for `\token_if_eq_meaning:VNTF`.

Comment: @banbh It seems nothing has been done about this, the bug report is still open. I updated my MiKTeX distribution to the latest versions this morning, and this has now changed from warning to error, so compilation grinds to a halt. How annoying ...

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot. Your suggestion, plus commenting out the two `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` lines that produce the error, does the trick.

Comment: I've submitted https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/fnpct/pull-requests/3/bug-13